# Variogram with custom distance matrix

Tags: autocorrelation, spatial, variogram

I work in marine ecology and as such all of my distance matrices are constructed using the shortest possible marine route - i.e. avoiding any land. Here is a plot of my "marine distances" against "as the crow flies" distances" - which shows that marine distances are greater than the direct route:

[image]

I therefore have problems when trying to calculate a variogram, as you give the function your X and Y coords and it calculates the distance matirx for you. Does anyone know of a way to calcualte a variogram but suppling your own distance matrix? I want to use the output to decide on an appropriate spatial autocorrelation structure so I can create my own correlation matrix for use in nlme.

Comment: It seems to me that the definition of empirical variogram (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variogram#Empirical_variogram) can accomodate arbitrary definitions of metric, or perhaps I'm missing something here?

Comment: Please explain specifically what "problems" you have in calculating a variogram.  Since you can compute the distances you want, it would appear there are no obstacles to the calculation.

Comment: Sorry, I should have stated that I was using nlme package in R. I have been trying to use GeoR also but both seem to require you to give the X and Y coordinates and then the function calculates your distances as part of the variogram calculation, and as you can see from the above figure I need a custom distance matirx. Maybe I need to manually calculate and not use R? Thanks